# Why doesn't this javascript date array work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to populate an array with a list of dates.

When I go back to retrieve a date in the array, they are all the same date.

```
var paydates = new Array();
var i;
var firstDate = new Date();
firstDate.setFullYear(2010, 11, 26); //set the first day in our array as 12/26/10

for (i=0; i < 200; i++) //put 200 dates in our array
{
    paydates[i] = firstDate;
    firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate()+14); //add 14 days
    document.write("1st: " + i + ":" + paydates[i] + "<br />");
    //this lists the dates correctly
}

//when I go back to retrieve them:
for (i=0; i < 200; i++)
{
    document.write("2nd: " + i + ":" + paydates[i] + "<br />");
    //this lists 200 instances of the same date
}
```

It's probably something stupid, but I'm at a loss.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your loop, you assign `paydates[i]` a reference to `firstDate`. At the end of 200 iterations, all 200 locations in the `paydates` array are pointing to the last `firstDate`.

You should create a new `Date` instance in each iteration and *then* assign it to an index in the `paydates` array.

Also, you'll notice that the first date listed in your example is **not** 12/26/2010, but 1/9/2011. I'm not sure if that's a mistake or intentional, but as your code is, the first `firstDate` isn't the date you used to seed your array of dates.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7dNKj/2/) of a working example that also simplifies your code a little bit. Here is the barebones code from the fiddle:

```
var paydates = []; // new array
var firstDate = new Date(2010, 11, 26); // seed date

for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    paydates.push(new Date(firstDate.getTime()));
    firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() + 14); // add 14 days
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace the first loop with:

```
var temp;

for (i=0; i < 200; i++) //put 200 dates in our array
{
    temp = new Date(firstDate.getTime());
    paydates[i] = temp;
    firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate()+14); //add 14 days
    document.write("1st: " + i + ":" + paydates[i] + "<br />");
}
```

The problem was that you were storing a reference to your one and only firstDate object to each index in your array.

Comment: I would declare `var temp;` outside of the `for` loop. JavaScript is function-scoped, so that's what it comes down to, anyway. Better to be explicit about it.

Comment: Yes, `var temp` is better declared outside at the start of the function. It will actually save the run-time the hassle of ignoring the redeclaration every time. Answer edited.

Comment: How about forgetting about `temp` and using `paydates[i] = new Date(firstDate.getTime());` as the first line in the for-loop?

Comment: @Cory: I was just about to post a new answer to suggest that, but I see you beat me to it in your latest edit. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You must create a `new Date` based on firstDate to get individual date to each element in array

Instead:

```
paydates[i] = firstDate;
firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate()+14); //add 14 days
```

write:

```
paydates[i] = new Date( firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate()+14));
```